# Linker problem when using sqrt function (C, gcc)

Tags: c, gcc, linker-errors

I have a strange problem when I try to compile the below minimal example. The first call to `sqrt` poses no problem, but the second one raises a linker error which I don't understand because I do specify the math library when calling `gcc`. When I comment the second line, it compiles/links correctly.

Here is the code:

```c
// File wtf_sqrt.c
#include <math.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int x = 3;  // Just an int...
  
  sqrt(3);  // This line works fine
  sqrt(x);  // But this one seems to give the linker trouble. Why?
  
  return 0;
}
```

Here is my compilation command:

```bash
gcc -lm -o wtf_sqrt wtf_sqrt.c
```

And here is the error returned:

```
/tmp/ccgQN7y7.o: In function `main':
wtf_sqrt.c:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I use `gcc` version 7.5.0 on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. `libc6-dev` is installed (proof is, `sqrt` works when I use it as in the first line of `main`). The code was written in `gedit`, so it should not be a problem with a blank character. Not sure what other info I can give you…

At this point, I really suspect this is a problem with my config/distribution, but I wanted some external advice.

Comment: runs fine for me on cent os 7, may be the os you are using does not have it installed

Comment: Order of arguments _might_ matter. Try moving `-lm` to after all of your source/object files.

Comment: `sqrt(3);` can be replaced by the compiler with the square root of 3. Or optimized out, since it is not doing anything.

Comment: Please see [Link order of libraries](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/an_introduction_to_gcc/gccintro_18.html)

Comment: Libraries are searched where they appear on the command line, so if `sqrt` is not referenced by the files that precede it, it may not be included.  Move the `-lm` option to the end and it should work.

Comment: I think this is it, thank you so much!

Comment: [-lm doesnt work unless it's at the end of the command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46722261/995714), [Why does the order of '-l' option in gcc matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11893996/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question actually has two parts, each of which is a duplicate of prior questions.

The fact that `sqrt` does not cause a link error when called with a constant argument is that the compiler evaluates it during compilation, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711915/sqrt-from-math-h-causes-linker-error-undefined-reference-to-sqrt-only-when-the?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C74.7437), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533594/sqrt-function-not-working-with-variable-arguments), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267041/c-math-sqrt-and-gcc-lm-option).

The fact that a link error is obtained even when `-lm` is included in the link is that `-lm` must be listed after modules that use the math library, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824439/c-math-linker-problems-on-ubuntu-11-10), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722261/lm-doesnt-work-unless-its-at-the-end-of-the-command), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893996/why-does-the-order-of-l-option-in-gcc-matter).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments by users aragaer, Weather Vane and Tom Karzes, the problem was the position of `-lm` in the compilation command. I falsely supposed that providing it first would be the correct way since then the linker might know where to find the function, but instead I should have provided it last so that the linker would already know that I need `sqrt` from my program. In fact, it is not only the order of `-l` options that matter, but also the order of files (to be) compiled. So the correct command is:

```
gcc -o wtf_sqrt wtf_sqrt.c -lm
```

As explained by user Weather Vane, the first call to `sqrt` is probably replaced or removed due to an optimization, thus producing no error.

Answer (score -1):

The problem might be in the argument that `sqrt()` takes. This is the function in `math.h` header:

```
_Check_return_ _CRT_JIT_INTRINSIC double __cdecl sqrt(_In_ double _X);
```

As you can see, the parameter type the function takes is a double. In your first `sqrt()` call, you pass the value of 3 by just typing it inside the parenthesis - the compiler probably treats this 3 as a double and compiles successfully. But in the second call, you pas as an argument `x`, which is an `int` (and you don't convert it into `double`). As C doesn't support function overloading, the compiler can't find the `sqrt` function which takes an `int` parameter and it pops up an error. Casting `x` into double should fix the problem:

```
sqrt((double)x);
```

Comment: The function which I pasted in here is from windows header, and you're using Ubuntu. But even in Linux "math.h" header shows that "sqrt" takes a double as a parameter

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. However, I forgot to mention that I already tried to cast `x` to `double` or even change the type of the variable, but it changes nothing. Plus, I found many examples on the web using `sqrt` on an `int` so I suppose it is not a problem.

Comment: `As C doesn't support function overloading, the compiler can't find the sqrt` makes no sense - C has implicit conversion, which occurs when calling a function.